# undefined label: loop3 inside firestore

Tags: java, android, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore, break

I want to break the outer loop when the condition is fulfilled inside the `firestore` query:

```
loopLebel:
for (int i = 10; i > 0; i++) {
    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                loop1:
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                    if (queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("Name").equals(list.get(finalI1).name)) {
                        HospitalData data = new HospitalData(list.get(finalI1).name, numberFormat.format(distanceKilometer), list.get(finalI1).rating.toString() + "/5.0", true, list.get(finalI1).latitude, list.get(finalI1).longitude);
                        hospitalDataList.add(data);
                        break loopLebel;
                    }
                }
            }
            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            HospitalAdapter hospitalAdapter = new HospitalAdapter((ArrayList<HospitalData>) hospitalDataList, HospitalListActivity.this);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(HospitalListActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(hospitalAdapter);
            hospitalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

The code is generating the following error message:

> error: undefined label: loopLebel

Outside the query, the `loopLebel` label is identified, but inside the query, the `loopLebel` label is not recognized.

Comment: Breaking loops is designed for nested loops which is definitely not the case here.  Aside comment: It's an endless loop: `for(int i =10;i>0;i++)` - that is it runs until Integer overflow occurs.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct a new `OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>` instance within `loop2`, the current implementation of the `onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task)` method will no longer have the outer code (`loop3`) in scope, which is why you're seeing the `undefined label: loop3` error message.

To solve the issue you can take the following steps (adjusting as necessary to meet your specific goals / requirements):

1. Drop the `loop3` label usage
2. Define a flag variable in its place
3. Reference the outer flag variable within `OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>`
4. Set the value of the flag variable within the inner scope (`loop1`)
5. Add a flag check in the outer scope (`loop3`) and break accordingly:

   ```
   // Step 1 & Step 2:
   boolean loopThreeFlag = false;
   for (/* ... */) {
       //...
       query.get().addOnCompleteListener(
           new OnCompleteListener() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                   //...
                   if (queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("Name")
                       .equals(list.get(finalI1).name)) {
                           //...
                           // Step 3 & Step 4:
                           OuterScopeClass.this.loopThreeFlag = true;
                   }
               }
           }
           //...
       });
       //Step 5:
       if (loopThreeFlag) {
           break; //no label required
       }
   }
   ```